# Aggregation not giving data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mongodb, mongorepository

**summary**- > I am getting records from subscription table where date is in between, then from the obtained data , i am taking a look up in particiapant table to get participant related data.

**problem**-> I am getting all field as null except _id in particpantDto that too the _id is some random id.

I am printing subs data , sunbscriptions is getting proper data.but when passing tow stages in aggreation then the problem is occuring.

**note**-> all the fields name are correct. Ignore the red lines in code.
[image]